ApplicationInsights.Config file transofrmation
We have ApplicationInsights.Config which is at root directory like Web.Config. I would like to apply transformation for the same. I was able to use the SlowCheetah Package which does the Job based on release / debug configuration and put the transformation file to bin folder. So now we have 2 ApplicationInsights.Config - one at root directory and other one at bin folder. Based on below article it will pick from root directory always, so how can i push to root directory transformation using this package.
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/main/examples/.NET%20Config%20File/Readme.md


Based on below article it will pick from root directory always,


Yes, by default when the Application is build the changes of root ApplicationInsights.config will be reflected to the bin ApplicationInsights.config file.

To change the transformation to root config directory you can set the command in Pre-build event command line.

Right click on the Application folder => Properties => Build Events

Add the below command in the command line.


copy $(TargetDir)ApplicationInsights.Debug.Config $(ProjectDir)ApplicationInsights.Config


This can be added either in .csproj.



When we run the application locally, we choose Debug option.



So, I am setting the command to copy the Debug file changes to the root directory config file.

Do the required changes in the ApplicationInsights.Debug.config and build the application.

Change the properties of the Target config file (here I am using Debug).



Build Action - Content
Copy to Output Directory - Copy always/Copy if newer


Build /Run the application now.

You can see the configuration of Debug file is copied to the root config file.
(It will also be copied to the bin folder, but we need the root config file. Any how the app will pick the root file).



Change the command line target based on your requirement(Debug/Release).
Refer devcodef1 blog for more details.
